# Magento Price Formatting - 2 or 3 decimal places

Tags: php, magento, currency

I have a requirement to set prices on certain items to 3 decimal places. I have achieved this by changing the 'precision' variable to 3, however this now means that every price on the site is displayed to 3 decimal places (ie: an empty shopping cart shows as £0.000). I want to only show the 3rd decimal place if it's required but I'm not sure where to find this in the code base. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: To set price upto 3 decimals for specific products, you can set an attribute from admin for that products and in frontend you can check if the attribute value is set or not. If its set then dispaly upto 3 decimal places and if not then the regular price format.

Comment: Where did you set the 'precision' to 3 ?

Comment: I followed the instructions in this post: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16337/P30/

Comment: You want this price on certain items only i.e. you have to filter that items and then set price upto 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Try Using this,

```
echo number_format($product->getPrice(), '2', '.', ',')
```

or

```
echo number_format($product->getPrice(), '3', '.', ',')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know whereabouts in the code base the prices are formatted so that I can decide whether the price needs to be displayed to 2 or 3 decimals places.